# C# getting error on decrypting byte[] from a file

Tags: c#, security, encryption, io, aes

I wrote this code to encrypt a text and write the encrypted text to a file and then decrypt it from the file. But I get this exception: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'The input data is not a complete block.' When I use a byte[] for storing data, it works perfect but it seems that it cant correctly convert a file to byte[]. I also tried File.ReadAllBytes but I got the same error. Please Help me.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string decrypted;
            byte[] encrypted;
            Console.Write("Enter a text to encrypt : ");
            string plaintext = Console.ReadLine();
            using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
            {
                encrypted = AesEncryption.Encrypt(plaintext, aes);
                File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\sepita\Desktop\My.txt", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encrypted), Encoding.UTF8);
                decrypted = AesEncryption.Decrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\sepita\Desktop\My.txt")), aes);
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Encrypted : {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encrypted)}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Decrypted : {decrypted}");
        }
    }
    static class AesEncryption
    {
        public static byte[] Encrypt(string plaintext, Aes aes)
        {
            byte[] encrypted;
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor();
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                    {
                        writer.Write(plaintext);
                    }
                    encrypted = memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
            return encrypted;
        }
        public static string Decrypt(byte[] encrypted, Aes aes)
        {
            string decrypted = null;
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor();
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(encrypted))
            {
                using (CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        decrypted = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            return decrypted;
        }
    }
```

Comment: is this possible to decrypt the encrypted data?

Comment: Yes. I am able to decrypt it successfully when I use a variable to store encrypted data. But as soon as I store it in a file, I'm not able to decrypt it.

Comment: Then, can you try changing to default encoding instead of UTF8?

Comment: What is the default encoding?

Comment: `Encoding.Default` in place of `Encoding.UTF8`

Comment: I did that but the same problem occurs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215819/discussion-between-vivek-nuna-and-mahan-lameie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of your `Encrypt` function is binary data. It would be pure luck if this were a valid UTF8 string, so `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encrypted)` will not work in general.

Replacing it by

```
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\sepita\Desktop\My.bin", encrypted);
            decrypted = AesEncryption.Decrypt(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\sepita\Desktop\My.bin"), aes);
```

will work.
If you want a text file, use BASE64 conversion on the binary data:

```
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\sepita\Desktop\My.txt", Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted));
            decrypted = AesEncryption.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\sepita\Desktop\My.txt")), aes);
```

Comment: Which one is better? storing encrypted data as byte array or as base64string?

Comment: Define "better". What are your requirements?